# Why won't my images from my computer show up on html?

Tags: html, css, image

[image][image]Why won't my images from my computer show up in my html file I had no issue using images from the web using the url. I saved my html file, css and images all in on folder but it doesn't show up on the website. This is the code I used using Sublime Text Editor.

```
<div>
  <img src="/images/profile-pic.jpg"/>
  <h1 id="myname">John Smith</h1>
  <h3>Web developer</h3>
  <p>{{ pause and ponder }}</p>
</div>
  </div class="intro">
```

Comment: Probably because `/images/profile-pic.jpg` is not the URL to your image. You need to debug this. Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Look at the URL being requested for the image (compare it to what you expect) and the response you get for it.

Comment: If you are keeping the HTML, CSS and JS file in one folder.. then probably you are mistaken with the path of the image. If the image and html are in same folder without any other subfolder of images, then it must be like this ```<img src="profile-pic.jpg"/>```

Comment: I’m not clear where you are holding your files/serving your HTML from. Are you on a server or all on you local machine?

Comment: I'm holding my files on my computer desktop in a folder containing the html file, css file and a folder containing all the images I'm going to use. I just added a screenshot to the original question of how it looks in my text editor.

Answer (score -1):

Now you provided screenshots, I can try to help better. In the folder tree, you can see folder named Portfolio and folder named Images are on same level.  Because of this, when you are inside of folder Portfolio, you should navigate one level up.

Please try to use

```
<img src="../images/profile-pic.jpg">
```

Comment: I have a folder on my desktop containing the html file, css file and a folder containing all the images I'm going to use. I added a screenshot to the original question to show how it looks like in my text editor. The image name and extension are correct as far as I can see.

Comment: Please don't post answers like this because this is a comment. If you keep doing this you will be rendered unable to ask questions in SO due to the downvotes you going to receive. So please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), I'm trying to help not being rood.

Answer (score -1):

Another easy way to do this.

Go to your files on your system, navigate to the folder where your image is stored right click and click properties then copy out the address there.

Answer (score -1):

Just give a correct path of the image in the html file and remove the forward slash (/) behind the path.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you're in a new directory and need to come back up one level.  You could try:

```
<img src="../images/profile-pic.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Now on folder structure, this is how you arrange your documents.

First create a folder for your entire website. Let's call it "Codes"
Then in codes add the HTML file and name it "index"(easier for the browser to recognize when hosting) the along side the index create another folder for your additional material. Example images, font files, CSS files,videos and lot more. Name the folder asset. Then in asset, create a folder for keeping the images only, another for CSS files and another for font files.

Then you are done
Copy address from the first folder created( this is easier)